# Is this reasoning in this type of proof writing correct?

Tags: proof-writing

So Im encountering some excercises of the type:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $S,T$ non empty subsets not necessairily distinct. Show that $ST=G$ or $|G| \geq |T|+|S|$

So in general I try to prove this in the following way: I start by saying, if $ST=G$ its done, so lets suppose that $ST \neq G$ and try to prove that $|G| \geq |T|+|S|$ and once Im able to prove this, I assume the proof is complete. I´ve been doing this for a while and just now It started to make some noise. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $T=G$ or $S=G$ we have that $TS = G$. Now assume that $TS \not= G$, meaning that $T,S$ are proper subgroups of $G$. Then we have that $[G:T] = n \ge 2 \implies \mid G \mid \; \ge 2 \mid T \;\mid $. Similarly $\mid\ G \mid \;\ge 2 \mid S \;\mid $. Adding these two inequalities yields the desire result.

Comment: The OP says subsets, not subgroups.

Comment: @AJY Ooops! I will try to fix the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reasoning is correct because you showed that if one of the conditions doesn't hold then the other holds. It is the same as if you wanted to show that if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $ab = 0$, then either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. Suppose $a \neq 0$, then $ab = a\cdot 0$ and since $a \neq 0$, we can cancel $a$ on both sides and conclude that $b = 0$, thus completing the proof.